# How can I transform an uncompressed file into zipped bytes?

Tags: java, zip

In Java for a JUnit test, I am trying to mock a function that downloads a Zip File from another external API's endpoint. To simulate the download, I need to zip a test file and transform it into bytes to use as the mock's return value. I do not need to write the zipped file back to the file system but use the bytes raw as they are.

```
mock(zipReturner.getZipBytes()).thenReturn(testFileAsZippedBytes("testFile.txt"))
```

```
private Optional<byte[]> testFileAsZippedBytes(String testFile) {
  ???
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing my answer, because all the other examples I found are much heavier, require many more lines of code looping over bytes, or require using external libraries to do the same thing.

To do this without the above, use a combination of ByteArrayOutputStream, as it has the `toByteArray` function,  ZipOutputStream to write zipped bytes to the ByteArrayOutputStream and FileInputStream to read the test file from the file system.

```
private Optional<byte[]> testFileAsZippedBytes(String filePath, String fileName) throws IOException {
  try (
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath + fileName);
  ) {
    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
    zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
    zipOutputStream.write(fileInputStream.readAllBytes());
    zipOutputStream.finish();
    return Optional.of(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
  }
}
```

Use `ZipEntry` to add the file as an entry to the `ZipOutputStream` and write the bytes to the zip. Use `zipOutputStream.finish()` to ensure all contents are written to the stream and are ready to be consumed in the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, otherwise it was my experience that you would only get partial data when you call `byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()`.